# Average calculation of MM:SS in SSRS expression

Tags: reporting-services, average, ssrs-expression

i have to average the MM:SS. I tried various ways but could not get this result. 
The source has data in hh:mm:ss format. 
I am looking to get output like Q3 below.

```
                                   April    May       June         Q2
Average speed to answer (mm:ss)   00:00:51  00:00:56  00:00:33     00:00:47
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try converting your data to seconds then get the average then convert it back to the correct format.